# How to create customized Android System Images from the AOSP?

Tags: android, android-source, image-file

I have already created the default Android system images (like `userdata.img`, `system.img`, `ramdisk.img`) by following the instructions at [Android page](http://source.android.com/source/download.html).

What I would like to create is customized Android system images from AOSP(by removing the apps & their code-dependencies, which are unnecessary for my target board, like the e-mail, browser) & run it on my target board so as to reduce the foot-print of the resulting system images & also speed-up the boot-up time of the target board.

Any pointers to do above mentioned customizations are welcome.

Comment: Android doesn't have a nice way to do this like menuconfig in the kernel. You will likely have to hack a lot of makefiles :(

Answer (score 3):

Edit this Makefile: `build/target/product/generic.mk` and remove the packages from the list. I won't bother going into how to compile, etc. Please note that doing this will not remove the code dependencies of the packages (you'll have to modify API in `dalvik/` or `frameworks/` which could get hairy), but it will eliminate the packages that are incorporated in the system image.